# Is it possible to launch Paytm from other apps without sdk for payment? If yes, how?

Tags: android, ios, payment, mobile-application, paytm

In native app (IOS/Android), i have items in my cart, now i want to place order and make payment through Paytm. I don't want to use Paytm SDK for some reason. Is it possible to make payment to Paytm acc wihout SDK? if Yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can pass the value or not, but yes you can open PayTM for receiving payment.
Here is how I have used it in one of my app.

You can create payment link [here](https://business.paytm.com/payment-link)

```
val link = "https://p-y.tm/*******"
```

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
intent.data = Uri.parse(link)
startActivity(intent)
```